# How should I start to learn JavaScript, jQuery, etc.? My programming knowledge is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I'm from a design background. My programming knowledge is zero. After learning XHTML and CSS I want to learn and get good command on JavaScript, jQuery, etc. How should I start?

This will be my first attempt to programming. I can use and edit readymade available jQuery/JavaScript scripts, but I can't make my own and can't do high level editing in readymade scripts.

Is there any other post on Stack Overflow, any link of start-up tutorial, or any book for my needs?

**Edit 1:**

This book will work best for me, "[DOM Scripting:
Web Design with JavaScript and the Document Object Model](http://www.friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=1590595335)".

[image]
<sub>(source: [friendsofed.com](http://www.friendsofed.com/img/cover/1590595335.jpg))</sub>

**Edit 2:**

Will my design background and knowledge of XHTML CSS help me to learn JavaScript quickly?

and is this correct? If I learn only jQuery then I will not be able to work with other JavaScript framework like [MooTools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools), [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework), etc. But if I learn core JavaScript then I would be able to work with all JavaScript frameworks and anything in JavaScript.

Comment: DOM Scripting is a brilliant book, it helped me a hell of a lot when I was learning.

Comment: I would recommend an introduction to programming as well. Are you considering courses or just books?

Comment: @MattMcKnight - anything which can teach me javascript

Comment: I can teach you jquery javascript and such in return I may need your designing skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chosen book is a good one. Learning jQuery is also a good stepping stone to learning Javascript if you're starting out with only design experience; it's great if you're familiar with CSS.

Also:

- [jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/)
- [Programming, the real basics](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/programming-the-real-basics/) by Chris Heilmann
- All other Javascript articles in the [Opera Web Standards Curriculum](http://www.opera.com/company/education/curriculum/)

Comment: Thanks for this link Programming, the real basics by Chris Heilmann

Comment: My Design background and knowledge of XHTML CSS Will help me to learn Javascript quickly?

Answer (score 1):

Start by learning some core JavaScript. Move on to the JavaScript DOM API. When you get the fundamentals move on to JavaScript libraries, like jQuery.

Comment: I'd say the exact opposite. It is very difficult to learn "core JavaScript", because most systems use JavaScript to work with the DOM. Learn the DOM and JavaScript at the same time, then you get to do a lot of fun stuff, and learn JS as well.

Comment: But with no programming knowledge at all he needs to learn about variables, statements, loops and so on. I'm not saying he should go in deep just learn the basic before starting to code.

Comment: is this book will work best for me? http://www.friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=1590595335

Comment: It seems to be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript, I would look at [the W3Schools tutorial](http://w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp). For JQuery, see the tutorials on [the JQuery page itself](http://learn.jquery.com/).

Comment: I'd avoid the W3Schoosl tutorial. It's awful. The very first page throws out examples of bad practices and gets facts wrong (with a misrepresentation of the relationship between JavaScript and ECMAScript being the biggest blunder). Page 2 is no better.

Comment: @David Dorward Thanks for ur comments to know us about ur experience with W3Schoosl tutorial

Comment: W3Schools is pretty bad.  I would use it more as a reference for the DOM and its events, properties and methods if you use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same boat as you in January this year. The book in your post is what I started to use too. I really recommend it. Also "learning jQuery" and "jQuery in action" were both helpful to me.

In my opinion, jQuery is like a shorthand (*and easier for a disigner who is used to working visually)* version Javascript. You'll see lots of techniques in the DOM Scripting book that take up multiple lines of code that you will be able to do in a line or two of jQuery.

Coming from a design background, I mostly use jQuery to add a little "pop" to my user experience, and leave the hardcore programming to the developers, but eventually I hope to be able to help them out.

Here are some sites that I found useful - good luck!

```
http://css-tricks.com/ (great entry level tutorials for designers)
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/16/jquery-examples-and-best-practices/
http://blog.themeforest.net/category/tutorials/
http://net.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/
```

Comment: But if i learn jquery only then I think i will not be able to work with other JS framework like Mootools, prototype etc. But if i learn core javascript then i would be able to work with all JS framework and anything in JS. am i right?

Comment: No definately learn both at the same time, but jQuery for me personally was easier to start with and helped me understand what what happening with all tha Javascript voodoo :)

Comment: What is the difference between Javascript , Unobtrousive Javascript and DOM? Do i need to learn all?

Comment: unobtrousive JS is basically making sure that the JS is just a enhancement layer, and someone who comes to your page who doesnt have JS enabled will have an acceptable user experience. I think its also known as progressive enhancement / graceful degredation. (This is my understanding, and it could be wrong!)

Here is the WP entry on the DOM - it explains it far better than I could:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

All of this is covered in the DOM Scripting book - Definately the best place to start

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to learn JavaScript or if you're satisfied just learning a library.  To fully understand a library you should know JavaScript.

I suggest a raw JavaScript:
[JavaScript From Null](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/javascript-from-null-video-series/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there not hundred of ways

- get yourself a good book
- take a look at the jquery documentation
- try it yourself

I think if you are looking only doing jQuery you don't have to learn the whole language, just stick with the basic and leave the class and comple topics, because using jQuery you would almost always write small piece of code with not too complex logic

Answer (score 0):

Well, jQuery is a javascript library, and it's a very easy to learn one, but you should get some base knowledge about javascript first, as you may end up not be able to do / understand some things, specially when you need to build something more complex.

jQuery has a fairly good documentation it its website.

To learn javascript, I recommend this :

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Should get you on the way. It has some quizes as well to test your knowledge after that :)

To well know about different behaviour in different browsers, always test, test, test (despite jQuery is quite stable and cross-browser, is never a loss to learn the differences by yourself)

Answer (score 0):

I agree w3schools is the best place to learn javascript

Comment: It isn't. It is one of the worst.

Comment: Could you please suggest better place then?

Comment: see http://w3fools.com/ for reasons why